# Solution to a complicated SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following db table `APP_USERS`

```
USER_NAME       OLD_STATUS       NEW_STATUS      STATUS_CHANGE_DATE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STEVE BALE      LOGGED_OUT       UNAVAILABLE     12/12/2012 5:04:24.736437 AM
STEVE BALE      UNAVAILABLE      AVAILABLE       12/12/2012 6:04:24.736437 AM
STEVE BALE      AVAILABLE        UNAVAILABLE     12/12/2012 7:31:08.591801 AM
STEVE BALE      UNAVAILABLE      AVAILABLE       12/12/2012 7:41:46.373138 AM
STEVE BALE      AVAILABLE        UNAVAILABLE     12/12/2012 8:30:21.218388 AM
STEVE BALE      UNAVAILABLE      AVAILABLE       12/12/2012 9:24:27.812461 AM
STEVE BALE      AVAILABLE        UNAVAILABLE     12/12/2012 10:44:52.724405 AM
STEVE BALE      UNAVAILABLE      LOGGED_OUT      12/12/2012 11:30:50.724405 AM
```

I have to display the user status begin date&time and end date&time for each status.

Something like user UNAVAILABLE from 12/12/2012 5:04:24.736437 AM to 12/12/2012 6:04:24.736437 AM.

Comment: Do you need to show a record for the initial "LOGGED_OUT" record... and if so, what would the "from" date/time be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need the "next" record, because the status seems to be changing.  You can do this with the lead function:

```
select user_name, new_status, status_change_date as StartTime,
       lead(status_change_date) over (partition by user_name order by status_change_date) as EndTime
from app_users
```